# Jmeter: control the number of requests happening at one time

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I'm doing performance testing on an app that does transactions.
I have 25 threads but only 5 unique IDs.

Here's my problem:
To avoid concurrency issue, I want to limit the number of requests being made during a buy/sell transaction to only 5 (cuz only 5 unique IDs). How do I achieve this in Jmeter?

Please be detailed in answer as i'm a total noobie. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the execution rate to the specified number of requests per unit of time using the following test elements:

- [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)
- [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer)
- [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)

All of them are capable of "pausing" JMeter threads to the specified throughput (# of requests per minute/second)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)

> The purpose of the SyncTimer is to block threads until X number of threads have been blocked, and then they are all released at once.

With `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` as 5